# How to Create A Time-Spiral Graph Using R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, lattice

is there any way to plot a graph like this in R and have the same 12 axes on it with thier name ?

here's a pic for the graph.
[image: Photo for the graph]

here's a piece of my data

```
        Date1  Time TravelTime
1  2016-09-04 13:11         34
2  2016-09-04 13:12         34
3  2016-09-04 13:13         33
4  2016-09-04 13:14         33
5  2016-09-04 13:15         33
6  2016-09-04 13:16         43
7  2016-09-04 13:17         44
8  2016-09-04 13:18         44
9  2016-09-04 13:19         40
10 2016-09-04 13:20         39
```

here's the output from dput

```
structure(list(Date1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2016-09-04", class = "factor"), Time = structure(1:10, .Label = c("13:11", 
"13:12", "13:13", "13:14", "13:15", "13:16", "13:17", "13:18", 
"13:19", "13:20"), class = "factor"), TravelTime = c(34L, 34L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 40L, 39L)), .Names = c("Date1", 
"Time", "TravelTime"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

here's my data for 5 days

[Data1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2lPFjKRVKWeGJTbVdTVDgzTEE)

---

here's another graph that shows the Time-Spiral ... May you please change your graph to spiral, not a circular ?

[image]

i got the graph from this link
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Condegram_Spiral_Plot.png)

Comment: Duplicate of deleted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429355/time-spiral-using-r

Comment: I looked on the good questions, searched for every post that may has answer for my question and i found that my question is in a good way ... it wasn't good at the beggin but now it's like other questions i saw ... i showed my data, and pic for my graph, and provided the data .... what else i should do ? plus i waited 2days,  i did what u told me to do... so it's not fair ...

Comment: you're not suppose to delete questions, you're suppose to edit the original. just for future information.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The overall approach is to summarize the data into time bins (I used 15-minute bins), where each bin's value is the average travel time for values within that bin. Then we use the POSIXct date as the y-value so that the graph spirals outward with time. Using `geom_rect`, we map average travel time to bar height to create a spiral bar graph.

First, load and process the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

dat = read_excel("Data1.xlsx")

# Convert Date1 and Time to POSIXct
dat$time = with(dat, as.POSIXct(paste(Date1, Time), tz="GMT"))

# Get hour from time
dat$hour = as.numeric(dat$time) %% (24*60*60) / 3600

# Get date from time
dat$day =  as.Date(dat$time)

# Rename Travel Time and convert to numeric
names(dat)[grep("Travel",names(dat))] = "TravelTime"
dat$TravelTime = as.numeric(dat$TravelTime)
```

Now, summarize the data into 15-minute time-of-day bins with the mean travel time for each bin and create a "spiral time" variable to use as the y-value:

```
dat.smry = dat %>% 
  mutate(hour.group = cut(hour, breaks=seq(0,24,0.25), labels=seq(0,23.75,0.25), include.lowest=TRUE),
         hour.group = as.numeric(as.character(hour.group))) %>%
  group_by(day, hour.group) %>%
  summarise(meanTT = mean(TravelTime)) %>%
  mutate(spiralTime = as.POSIXct(day) + hour.group*3600)
```

Finally, plot the data. Each 15-minute hour-of-day bin gets its own segment, and we use travel time for the color gradient and the height of the bars. You could of course map fill color and bar height to two different variables if you wish (in your example, fill color is mapped to month; with your data, you could map fill color to date, if that is something you want to highlight).

```
ggplot(dat.smry, aes(xmin=as.numeric(hour.group), xmax=as.numeric(hour.group) + 0.25, 
                     ymin=spiralTime, ymax=spiralTime + meanTT*1500, fill=meanTT)) +
  geom_rect(color="grey40", size=0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,24), breaks=0:23, minor_breaks=0:24,
                     labels=paste0(rep(c(12,1:11),2), rep(c("AM","PM"),each=12))) +
  scale_y_datetime(limits=range(dat.smry$spiralTime) + c(-2*24*3600,3600*19), 
                   breaks=seq(min(dat.smry$spiralTime),max(dat.smry$spiralTime),"1 day"),
                   date_labels="%b %e") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="green", mid="yellow", high="red", midpoint=35) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw(base_size=13) + 
  labs(x="Hour",y="Day",fill="Mean Travel Time") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(colour="grey60", size=0.3))
```

[image]

Below are two other versions: The first uses `geom_segment` and, therefore, maps travel time only to fill color. The second uses `geom_tile` and maps travel time to both fill color and tile height.

#### `geom_segment` version

```
ggplot(dat.smry, aes(x=as.numeric(hour.group), xend=as.numeric(hour.group) + 0.25, 
                     y=spiralTime, yend=spiralTime, colour=meanTT)) +
  geom_segment(size=6) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,24), breaks=0:23, minor_breaks=0:24,
                     labels=paste0(rep(c(12,1:11),2), rep(c("AM","PM"),each=12))) +
  scale_y_datetime(limits=range(dat.smry$spiralTime) + c(-3*24*3600,0), 
               breaks=seq(min(dat.smry$spiralTime), max(dat.smry$spiralTime),"1 day"),
               date_labels="%b %e") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="green", mid="yellow", high="red", midpoint=35) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw(base_size=10) + 
  labs(x="Hour",y="Day",color="Mean Travel Time") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(colour="grey60", size=0.3))
```

[image]

#### `geom_tile` version

```
ggplot(dat.smry, aes(x=as.numeric(hour.group) + 0.25/2, xend=as.numeric(hour.group) + 0.25/2, 
                     y=spiralTime, yend=spiralTime, fill=meanTT)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height=meanTT*1800*0.9)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,24), breaks=0:23, minor_breaks=0:24,
                     labels=paste0(rep(c(12,1:11),2), rep(c("AM","PM"),each=12))) +
  scale_y_datetime(limits=range(dat.smry$spiralTime) + c(-3*24*3600,3600*9), 
                   breaks=seq(min(dat.smry$spiralTime),max(dat.smry$spiralTime),"1 day"),
                   date_labels="%b %e") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="green", mid="yellow", high="red", midpoint=35) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw(base_size=12) + 
  labs(x="Hour",y="Day",color="Mean Travel Time") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(colour="grey60", size=0.3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so so much, i want to show the travel time as groups, and the time will be the axes, each circle on the graph will be the days, and May you show axes on the graph, Please ? it will be more comfortable for eyes to find the TravelTime, you'll find the description of my graph on the top of pic.

Comment: example: if you take a look on my graph, from 8am to 9am you gonna find  most of days are green which mean TravelTime is normal, it means no 
congestion.

Comment: Please, May you do it with my data? i'm not so good in R,  May legends represent as Low TravelTime Value represent as Green and highest Value represent Red.

Comment: Is it circle graph ?

Comment: I'll update my answer this evening to respond to your questions and comments. Note, however, that in your original small data sample, all the rows have times that fall within a ten-minute period. Note that line segments for each of these rows will therefore all be plotted one on top of the other. Do you want these data grouped in some way, for example, mean travel time within 15 or 30 minute blocks?

Comment: Thanks alot for helping, do u mean instead of making the time every 2 mins ... take the mean for every 15mins ? i think it's a good idea, 15mins is good ... when i use ur code, it gives me this warning massage 
"Removed 661 rows containing missing values (geom_segment). "
and the graph don't start from 1pm, it starts from 12 pm .i'll attach a photo

Comment: you are perfect , you are awesome :D, one small last thing Please... this graph looks like circular graph .... i meat by spiral that the end of the circle will be the begging of the other circle .. i really appreciate what you did, you look like an artist :D .

Comment: i attached another pic for Time-Spiral graph

Comment: really i don't know what should i tell you .. by doing this graph you helped me alot, thanks so so much, i really appreciate what you did, you incredibly awesome :D ,

Comment: I realized how to make a spiral bar plot similar to what you posted. See update.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: hahahaha ... it looks so good, it visualizes data in a very good way, color and height, it's very useful, it's a masterpiece.

Comment: @eipi10, May you help me in something ? instead of colouring the Mid point in  `scale_fill_gradient2(low="green", mid="yellow", high="red", midpoint=35)` ... is there any way to put the colour all the quantiles ? like min,0.25,0.5,0.75,max ?

Comment: This is really cool! I'm trying to figure out how to achieve a similar plot with discrete events that have a start time and stop time. I've been editing your code trying to produce it but having a hard time. Could you also give an example of what discrete events would look like?

Comment: I'd need to see some data to get an idea of what you mean. Might be best to post a new question and link to this one.

Comment: Good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575723/creating-a-temporal-range-time-series-spiral-plot